# Wildfly 13.0.0.Final error UT005014: Failed to parse request: io.undertow.util.BadRequestException: UT000165: Invalid character ä in request-target

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, internationalization, wildfly

We have recently migrated and deployed our application.EAR (API's) packages in wildfly 13.0.0.Final from GlassFish 3 in Linux environment. While testing application api's its not supporting scandic characters and giving below error (Error copied from server.log from wildfly). But the same test request working fine with the application api's deployed in GlassFish server. I tried to study so many blogs related to wildfly but could not get any solutions. Could some one help here please.

I tired below setting changes in standalone.xml file to set the charset to UTF-8, but its not helped.

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" url-charset="UTF-8"/>

<servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">
```

**2018-07-13 17:06:45,189 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default I/O-4) UT005014: Failed to parse request: io.undertow.util.BadRequestException: UT000165: Invalid character ä in request-target**
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.handleQueryParameters(HttpRequestParser.java:523)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.beginQueryParameters(HttpRequestParser.java:486)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.handlePath(HttpRequestParser.java:410)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpRequestParser.handle(HttpRequestParser.java:248)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:187)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:147)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:93)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:52)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:291)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:286)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.nio.QueuedNioTcpServer$1.run(QueuedNioTcpServer.java:131)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)

Below is the request XML which we are sending to application deployed in both Wildfly and GlassFish

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <StartHeader SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/soap/conversation/">
            <callbackLocation>http://TESTUI</callbackLocation>
        </StartHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ListAttributeValues xmlns="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:v001="http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/listAttribteValuesRequest/v002" xmlns:v0011="http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/v002">
            <listAttributeValuesRequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/listAttributeValuesRequest/v002 http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/listAttributeValuesRequest/v002" xmlns="http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/listAttributeValuesRequest/v002" xmlns:spec="http://xml.comptel.com/NIMS/address/v002" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <spec:searchItemList>
                    <spec:attribute>
                        <spec:name>district</spec:name>
                        <spec:value>Jär</spec:value>
                    </spec:attribute>
                </spec:searchItemList>
                <spec:attributeName>district</spec:attributeName>
                <spec:maxItems>100</spec:maxItems>
            </listAttributeValuesRequest>
        </ListAttributeValues>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I suspect that you need to tell wildfly to work in a Unicode context.

Comment: Are you passing that character - ä - as a query parameter in a URL?

Comment: @stdunbar: Application deployed in wildfly and galssfish are web application, so we are sending below XML as a query string.   spec:searchItemList>
     <spec:attribute>
      <spec:name>district</spec:name>
      <spec:value>Jär</spec:value>
     </spec:attribute>
    </spec:searchItemList>

Comment: @Dragonthoughts: You mean something needs to be changed i wildfly configurations or i need to send some parameter in my input request xml to tell wildfly to work in a Unicode context?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to fix the problem with help of JBossDevelopers community

I don't think it's the contents of SOAP message that is the problem, but the URI that is used to touch the web service. Problem can be fixed using any of the below option. Option 2 will be recommended for latest wildfly versions where undertow subsystem introduced.

1. By adding the following Java option to startup script :

**-Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true**

2. or we can set the **allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" and url-charset="windows-1252"** flags in the undertow subsystem in standalone.xml file.

I think these options were added as part of the undertow:6.0 schema as attributes of the https-listener and http-listener elements.

See here:

[wildfly/wildfly-undertow_6_0.xsd](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/main/resources/schema/wildfly-undertow_6_0.xsd) at master · wildfly/wildfly · GitHub

An example configuration:

[wildfly/undertow-6.0.xml](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/test/resources/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/undertow-6.0.xml) at master · wildfly/wildfly · GitHub